# How can we trigger a parameterised jenkins release job manually (it takes Pull request ID) only if Pull request build job was successful?

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have setup a jenkins pipeline job which gets triggered whenever a new Pull request arrives on my github repository main branch (this job builds and run tests for that specific PR).

Now, I have created another parameterised jenkins pipeline job which takes Pull request id and release the artifacts to artifactory. I want that upon triggering this parameterized job manually, it should fail if the 1st jenkins job configured on the Pull request has failed. Else, if 1st job was successful, then, release pipeline can continue its work.

Is there a way to do this?

PS: I can add entire content of that first jenkins job in a stage before release pipeline stage, but that would make it time consuming.

Comment: I would trigger the release job from within pipeline job using `build job: "<release job name>"`. Anything else may lead to confusion. E.g. PR created - pipeline job succeeded - PR updated - release job triggered; should the release job succeed or fail?

Comment: I want to trigger this 2nd job manually only for now. Is there a way to do that and achieve above plan?